# Basic Social Media Integration, Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-html, social-media-like, twitter-share

I'm trying to implement social media integrations for my flutter application, deploying to both mobile and web. The mobile implementation with the [share package](https://pub.dev/packages/share) is working just fine, but since web is a bit newer, I've decided to just use basic html and js apis for things like **like** and **share** buttons, as you would find here for [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/), [twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview), and [linkedin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/follow-company-plugin).

When fed statically as src from html the buttons work fine. If I had some sort of server-side templating at my disposal such as thymeleaf or Django templates I might go that route to create parameterized HtmlElementView widgets (e.g. with template literals for shareable URLs), but instead I'm limited to the dart:html package.

This is fine in theory, but in practice for whatever reason I cannot load the necessary social media js apis like the following in time for the DOM to recognize them and correctly render, whether I prepare them in dart code or stick them in the header or body of the index.html file.

To prepare the payload in dart, I'd do something like this:

```dart
static final _FB_API_HEADER1 = DivElement()
    ..id = "fb-root";

  static final _FB_API_HEADER2 =
    ScriptElement()
    ..async = null
    ..defer = null
    ..crossOrigin = "anonymous"
    ..nonce = "plTxQNq6"
    ..src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0";

  static Element _createFacebookHeader() {
    Element _temp = DivElement();
    _temp.append(_FB_API_HEADER1);
    _temp.append(_FB_API_HEADER2);
    return _temp;
  }

  static get FB_API_HEADER => _createFacebookHeader();

static Element createFacebookButton(String linkToLikeAndShare) {
    return DivElement()
      ..appendHtml('<div class="fb-like" data-href="$linkToLikeAndShare" data-width="" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-share="true"></div>',
          validator: NodeValidatorBuilder()
            ..allowElement('div', attributes: ['data-share','data-size','data-action','data-layout','data-width','data-href'])
            ..allowHtml5(uriPolicy: ItemUrlPolicy())
            ..allowNavigation(ItemUrlPolicy())
            ..allowImages(ItemUrlPolicy()) );
  }
```

and then push to a view, like this:

```dart
DivElement _finalView = DivElement();
_finalView.append(SocialMediaApis.FB_API_HEADER);
_finalView.append(SocialMediaApis.createFacebookButton("mysite.com"));

// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'LikeAndShare',
      (int viewId) => _finalView,
    );
```

and built as a widget, like so:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            child: HtmlElementView(
              viewType: 'LikeAndShare',
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get past this? Perhaps some preloading mechanism?

For context I'm using Flutter version **1.23.0-18.1.pre** for compatibility, and I'm happy to share code where it might help.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Have you sorted this out as yet? I am trying to do the same thing and see that the pub.dev packages do not include web for social intergration.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'd since abandoned the effort. There's the share_plus package, but when I tested it many moons ago it seemed like it was trying to mimic iOS and Android system-level social media bindings, but in a weird browser-specific way that itself doesn't really work all that well on desktop. Perhaps this use-case is too peculiar? Social Media Companies locking down their apis doesn't help, either. Facebook for one used to be much more permissive.

Comment: Have you looked into Deep linking using firebase? may work?